# Does anyone have any experience that interceptor(i18n) will cause no value during postback?

Tags: post, struts2, internationalization

Assume I have this struts2 form

```
<s:form action="login" method="post">
    <s:textfield key="login_name" name="login_name"/>
    <s:submit></s:submit>
</s:form>
```

And also with this struts.xml setting

```
<constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="messageResource" />
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
<package name="login" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="login" class="actions.index.index">
        <interceptor-ref name="i18n"/>
        <result name="LOGIN_SUCCESS">/Main.jsp</result>
        <result name="LOGIN">/Login.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>
```

If I have added `<interceptor-ref name="i18n"/>` to the setting, login_name will have no value after form submitted; otherwise I can retrieve the value successfully.
If you want me to provide further detail, please just let me know. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding only one interceptor for your action by doing so all other interceptors are not included. The default stack already includes `i18n` interceptor so no point to add it by yourself.