# Getting 404 error when using dojo.xhrPost + struts?

Tags: struts2, dojo

I am not sure why this was happening. I have a struts form that will post to my struts action's method:

```
<s:form data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Form" action="SaveRec" method="POST" 
    enctype="multipart/form-data" theme="simple" id="frmRecord">
    <div class="item">
        ...
```

Basically, I just hit the link htp://example.com:8080/Test/SaveRec in browser and I will get a workable page, but after using these code, I will get the post 404 error(POST [http://example.com:8080/Test/SaveRec.action](http://example.com:8080/rBRAVO_Impl/SaveRec.action) 404 (Not Found) ):

```
dojo.connect(dojo.byId('btnSave'), 'onclick', function(event){
    // The parameters to pass to xhrPost, the message, and the url to send it to
    // Also, how to handle the return and callbacks.
    var xhrArgs = {
      form: dojo.byId("frmRecord"),
      handleAs: "json",
      load: function(data){
        console.log("Message posted. " + data);
      },
      error: function(error){
        console.log("Message failed to post, " + error);
      }
    }
    console.log("Message being sent...");
    // Call the asynchronous xhrPost
    var deferred = dojo.xhrPost(xhrArgs);
});
```

PS: I can run `invocation.invoke()` and print out message in my interceptor

**UPDATE:**

OK, I think the problem is the return type of action, I have added the interceptor into the action, however, I still cannot use the getter to retrieve the value:

```
<struts>
    <package name="testJson" extends="json-default">
        <action name="SaveRec" class="com.xyz.Test" method="saveRec">
        <interceptor-ref name="json">
                <param name="contentType">application/json</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
            <result name="success" type="json">
                <param name="root">saveResult</param>
            </result>
        </action>
        ...
```

Comment: See this question with answer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14122984/1700321.

Comment: I realize the problem is <s:token/> is missing out.